# TWYTHON . Getting user name from tweets. Generating friends list from username

Tags: python, tweets, twython

I am trying to mine data in a local area.

First I would like to Twython to search all tweets on twitter to find those tweets that contain a particular keyword, and then print those tweets. I have successfully written the few lines of code that do this:

```
from twython import Twython

TWITTER_APP_KEY = ''
TWITTER_APP_KEY_SECRET = ''
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ''

t = Twython(TWITTER_APP_KEY, TWITTER_APP_KEY_SECRET, TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,       TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

search = t.search(q='hello', count=100)

tweets = search['statuses']

    for tweet in tweets:
    print (tweet['text'], '\n')
```

Next, I want to generate the user name of the ID that tweeted the text (not just the ID but the actual username), and print it.

After this, I would like to generate the friends list of the particular user, and print it.

How can I get the user name and the friends list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate the username, you can look in the "user" section of each status. There will be a key called "screen_name" and its value is what you'll need.

In the user section, there is also an "id". You'll need to create a separate call using this id to get that user's followers. The twitter api (and twython) supports getting followers from an id. See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/ids